Android Accessibility app is not performing swipe gesture
I've been working on creating an Android app that can do a swipe-up gesture on the screen every 5 seconds. The idea is to make it scroll any app which is open such as reels on Instagram, or Facebook timeline or Pintrest.
I've made sure to give the app all the permissions it needs, set up the Android manifest properly, and configured the accessibility services. I've also put together what I think is the right code for the GestureAccessibilityService class.
But it's not doing what it's supposed to do. I've been trying to figure out what's wrong with the code. Please help.
accessiblity_service_config.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<accessibility-service
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:description="@string/accessibility_service_description"
    android:canRequestTouchExplorationMode="true"
    android:accessibilityFeedbackType="feedbackGeneric"
    android:accessibilityFlags="flagDefault"
    android:canPerformGestures="true"
    android:accessibilityEventTypes="typeAllMask"
    android:canRetrieveWindowContent="true"
    android:notificationTimeout="100"/>

Android Manifest
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"> 

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:dataExtractionRules="@xml/data_extraction_rules"
        android:fullBackupContent="@xml/backup_rules"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.ThumbD"
        tools:targetApi="31">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <service
            android:name=".GestureAccessibilityService"
            android:permission="android.permission.BIND_ACCESSIBILITY_SERVICE"
            android:exported="false">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.accessibilityservice.AccessibilityService"/>
            </intent-filter>
            <meta-data
                android:name=".GestureAccessibilityService"
                android:resource="@xml/accessibility_service_config"/>
        </service>
    </application>

</manifest>

GestureAccessibilityService.kt
class GestureAccessibilityService:AccessibilityService() {

    private val TAG = "GESTURE"

    private val handler = Handler(Looper.getMainLooper())
    private val gestureRunnable = object : Runnable {
        override fun run() {
            performSwipeUp()
            //dispatch(0f,0f,0f,200f, applicationContext)
            handler.postDelayed(this, 5000) // Repeat every 5 seconds (5000 milliseconds)
        }
    }
    override fun onAccessibilityEvent(event: AccessibilityEvent?) {
    }

    override fun onInterrupt() {
        // NO-OP
    }

    override fun onServiceConnected() {
        super.onServiceConnected()
        "onServiceConnected".logd()
        handler.postDelayed(gestureRunnable, 0)
    }

    override fun onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy()
        // Stop the repeating gesture when the service is destroyed
        handler.removeCallbacks(gestureRunnable)
    }

    private fun performSwipeUp() {
        val displayMetrics = resources.displayMetrics
        val screenHeight = displayMetrics.heightPixels

        val gestureDescription = GestureDescription.Builder()
            .addStroke(
                GestureDescription.StrokeDescription(
                    Path().apply {
                        moveTo(displayMetrics.widthPixels / 2f, screenHeight * 0.8f)
                        lineTo(displayMetrics.widthPixels / 2f, screenHeight * 0.2f)
                    },
                    0,
                    500
                )
            )
            .build()

        val result = dispatchGesture(gestureDescription, object : GestureResultCallback() {
            override fun onCompleted(gestureDescription: GestureDescription?) {
                super.onCompleted(gestureDescription)
                "Gesture completed".logd()
            }

            override fun onCancelled(gestureDescription: GestureDescription?) {
                super.onCancelled(gestureDescription)
                "Gesture cancelled".logd()
            }
        }, null)
        "STATUS $result".logd()
    }

    fun dispatch(x: Float, y: Float,xx: Float, yy: Float, context:Context): Boolean {
        try {
            val accessibilityManager = context.getSystemService(Context.ACCESSIBILITY_SERVICE) as AccessibilityManager

            val isEnabled = accessibilityManager.isEnabled
            if (isEnabled) {
                val result = dispatchGesture(
                    buildSwipe(x, y, xx, yy),
                    object : GestureResultCallback() {
                        override fun onCompleted(gestureDescription: GestureDescription?) {
                            super.onCompleted(gestureDescription)
                            "Gesture completed".logd()
                        }

                        override fun onCancelled(gestureDescription: GestureDescription?) {
                            super.onCancelled(gestureDescription)
                            "Gesture cancelled".logd()
                        }
                    },
                    null
                )

                "STATUS $result".logd()
                return result
            } else {
                // Accessibility service is not enabled
                return false
            }
        }catch (e: Exception) {
            "Error dispatching gesture: ${e.message}".logd()
            e.printStackTrace()
            return false
        }
    }

    private fun buildSwipe(
        startX: Float,
        startY: Float,
        endX: Float,
        endY: Float
    ): GestureDescription {
        val swipePath = Path()
        swipePath.apply {
            moveTo(startX, startY)
            lineTo(endX, endY)
        }
        val swipeBuilder = GestureDescription.Builder()
        swipeBuilder.addStroke(GestureDescription.StrokeDescription(swipePath, 0, 100L))
        return swipeBuilder.build()
    }

}

MainActivity.kt
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
 
    private lateinit var binding: ActivityMainBinding
  
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        setContentView(binding.root)  

        /*Permissions*/
        val permissions = if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.UPSIDE_DOWN_CAKE) {
            listOf(
                Manifest.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE_SPECIAL_USE,
                Manifest.permission.BIND_ACCESSIBILITY_SERVICE
            )
        } else {
            listOf(Manifest.permission.BIND_ACCESSIBILITY_SERVICE)
        }

        checkPermissions(permissions) 

        if(isAccessibilityServiceEnabled(this)){
            "started sevices------->".logd()
        }
    }

    fun permissionAccessServices(view: View){
        openAccessibilitySettings(this)
    }

    
    private fun checkPermissions(permissions: List<String>){
        PermissionX.init(this)
            .permissions(permissions)
            .request { allGranted, grantedList, deniedList ->
                if (allGranted) {
                    Log.d("Permission","SuccessFull");
                } else {
                    Log.d("Permission","Failed $deniedList");
                }
            }
    }

    private fun isAccessibilityServiceEnabled(mContext: Context): Boolean {
        var accessibilityEnabled = 0
        val service: String = mContext.packageName + "/" + GestureAccessibilityService::class.java.canonicalName
        try {
            accessibilityEnabled = Settings.Secure.getInt(
                mContext.applicationContext.contentResolver,
                Settings.Secure.ACCESSIBILITY_ENABLED
            )
            "accessibilityEnabled = $accessibilityEnabled".logd()

        } catch (e: Settings.SettingNotFoundException) {
            "Error finding setting, default accessibility to not found: ${e.message}".logd()
        }
        val mStringColonSplitter = TextUtils.SimpleStringSplitter(':')
        if (accessibilityEnabled == 1) {
            "Accessibility Is Enabled".logd()
            val settingValue: String = Settings.Secure.getString(
                mContext.applicationContext.contentResolver,
                Settings.Secure.ENABLED_ACCESSIBILITY_SERVICES
            )
            if (settingValue != null) {
                mStringColonSplitter.setString(settingValue)
                while (mStringColonSplitter.hasNext()) {
                    val accessibilityService = mStringColonSplitter.next()
                    "AccessibilityService :: $accessibilityService $service".logd()
                    if (accessibilityService.equals(service, ignoreCase = true)) {
                        "accessibility is switched on!".logd()
                        return true
                    }
                }
            }
        } else {
            "accessibility is disabled".logd()
        }
        return false
    }
}


So, there was an error in the Android Manifest. The meta tag had incorrect values. If someone wants to create an auto-scroller, they can simply copy the code provided above and add the following code snippet to their Android Manifest. With this adjustment, they will have a functioning app capable of performing gestures on any app.
<service
            android:name=".GestureAccessibilityService"
            android:permission="android.permission.BIND_ACCESSIBILITY_SERVICE"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="true"
            android:foregroundServiceType="specialUse"
            android:process=":AccessibilityService">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.accessibilityservice.AccessibilityService"/>
            </intent-filter>
            <meta-data
            <-- android:name=".GestureAccessibilityService" -->
                android:name="android.accessibilityservice" // this is correct
                android:resource="@xml/accessibility_service_config"/>
        </service>


I was having a LOT of trouble attempting to do something similar. I learned, through some trial and error, that attempting to use binding code alongside gesture code does not work. At least, it doesn't for me.
If you get rid of the binding, and use findByViewID, I bet it'll work just fine.
